# How to show on listview my audio recors from sdcard?

Tags: android, android-listview, audio-recording

I can record audio on sd card but, ı want to list records on a list view; my code has shown below

```
private void beginRecording() throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
        ditchMediaRecorder();
        File outFile=new File(OUTPUT_FILE);

        if(outFile.exists())
            outFile.delete();

        recorder=new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        recorder.setOutputFile(OUTPUT_FILE);
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
```

Comment: simply point out on your sound folder and show them in a listview

Comment: Well, but ı also want to click and play audio files which shown on list view , May u have any code sample for my instance.

Comment: Please show your code where you put the filenames in a listview first. Or show other specific code. Ask more specific questions. show that you tried and what you know.